# HTML center input buttons

Tags: html, css

Here is my code:

```
        <p align="center">Do you want to play the game?</p><br>
        <Input type = 'Submit' Name ='StartQuiz' value="Yes" align="center">
        <Input type = 'Submit' Name ='LogOut' value="No" align="center">
```

The buttons are not in the center. Do I have to use CSS for this? I read on the net to just use the simple align tag.

How should I go about aligning these buttons to the center?

Comment: @leppie: Almost. Try `style="text-align:center" instead`

Answer (score 16):

Align is deprecated on HTML5, so considered use CSS3 instead. The align attributte is to center the content and not the element itself.

The input element is inline-block by default, so, to center you need to put them inside a div as here:

```
<div style="text-align:center;">
    <input type="text" />
</div>
```

This is cause the inline-block elements share the same line with other elements and you need to center all elements that share the same line. The div element is a block element that display alone in one line.

So you have another option to center an input, and you can set to "display:block;" as here:

```
<input type="text" style="margin:0px auto; display:block;" />
```

See: http://jsfiddle.net/T4f3W/

Answer (score 2):

You should be using CSS for such styling. Rid of the HTML align attributes, add a wrapper, and center the text. Also note that the `<center>` tag and certain uses of `align=center` are deprecated as of HTML5.

```
<div>
    <p>Do you want to play the game?</p><br>
    <input type="submit" name="StartQuiz" value="Yes">
    <input type="submit" name="LogOut" value="No">
</div>
```

And for your CSS:

```
div
{
    text-align: center;
}​
```

Answer (score 0):

Define one div parent and give to `text-align center` in your css .

Hi Check to live demo http://jsfiddle.net/vdUEZ/

---

Remove `p tag align center` and give to one div

**Updated Live demo** http://jsfiddle.net/vdUEZ/1/

Answer (score 0):

```
<p align="center">Do you want to play the game?</p><br>
<div style="text-align: center">
        <Input type = 'Submit' Name ='StartQuiz' value="Yes"  align="center">
        <Input type = 'Submit' Name ='LogOut' value="No" align="center">
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Your strategy should work if you move the `<input>` tags inside the the `<p>` tag and remove the deprecated `align` attributes in the `<input>` tags. Even if you were to use the `align` attribute in an `<input>` tag, the [correct value would be `"middle"`](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_align.asp), not `"center"`. Try this code:

```
<p align="center">Do you want to play the game?<br>
    <Input type = 'Submit' Name ='StartQuiz' value="Yes">
    <Input type = 'Submit' Name ='LogOut' value="No">
</p>
```

It's also possible (preferred, actually) to use CSS for centering.

Answer (score -1):

chuck the inputs inside a `<center>` tag. check out the live demo http://jsfiddle.net/xA2kS/

Comment: <center> is deprecated in HTML 4.01.